# generate a CSV file in salesforce and transfer this into another server

Tags: ftp, salesforce

I have generated a XML file in Salesforce and now my problem is that i want to transfer this file into another server. Can i connect to another server using FTP, or is there any way out to transfer the file to another server.

This is an urgent task.

Any solutions wud be greatfully accepted.

Phaniraj N

Answer (score 0):

You can't FTP out, where do you store the file in Salesforce? What's the server on the other end?

You could serve the file up as a public page over sites, call a custom web service to transfer it, implement a web service to serve up the file, use data loader to extract from Salesforce on a regular basis and then a batch to upload to the other server, the list goes on but we'll need a bit more information on what you're dealing with!